# Is it technically possible to make Python / Ruby as performant as Common Lisp?

Tags: python, ruby, performance, common-lisp

It is said that Python/Ruby are [conceptually close to Common Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/lispfaq1.html).

I was wondering specifically - Being said to provide high performance to modern CL implementations, could the [Python Compiler for CMU Common Lisp](http://sci-hub.cc/10.1145/141478.141558) be used as a potential basis for a performant Python/Ruby compiler implementation?

Note: I realize languages *don't have* to be fast. I'm missing why they *have* to be slow if there's place for improvement.

---

Original phrasing, for context for the first 5 comments:

Title:

How come Python / Ruby are so much slower than Common Lisp?

Body:

This is not to start any language wars, just curiosity -

- As far as the Internet tells, the performance difference between Python/Ruby and Common Lisp is immense, even though CL is more dynamic, homoiconic etc.
- I read that Common Lisp implementations are fast due to implementing versions of the [Python Compiler for CMU Common Lisp](http://sci-hub.cc/10.1145/141478.141558).

My question is - if the speed "technology" has been out there for all those years, how come modern dynamic languages don't utilize it?

Comment: Performance does not have the same priority in each language...

Comment: Wasn't Rails abandoned due to performance issues?

Comment: Python & Ruby (and Perl before them) appeared on the scene primed by Common Lisp to the idea that "Programmer Time" is (sometimes) more valuable than "Computer Time". I.e., writing something **fast** which executes fast _enough_ is better than spending a lot of time on something marginally faster. The other major reason is that Python and Ruby (and R) are _glue_ languages. They call C libraries for real stuff. The only things they do "themselves" is (disk and network) i/o.

Comment: Not sure that is the correct term, but do you mean they are not bootstrapped?

Comment: Note the Pyhon compiler has nothing to do with Python the language (just in case there is a confusion)

Comment: @coredump hard to miss the irony though

Comment: Common Lisp was designed with the influence of compiler writers. It may have a lot of dynamic features but they are designed to allow for code to be compiled to something fast and the spec allows implementations to forgo some dynamism when it interacts with compilation (e.g define and compile `foo`, then `bar` which calls (and inlines) `foo` then redefine `foo` but `bar` won't change to this new definition). Lexical scoping allows for stack allocation, macros and `tagbody` allow succinct code to have good performance. Hash tables are slightly painful in CL. Most python objects are hash tables.

Comment: @DanRobertson  What made for that design decision?

Comment: Common Lisp was designed in the mid 1980's with the goal of unifying the current competing Lisp implementations of the time. Some of those had good compilers and their current users expected Lisp to be able to be compiled to something with reasonable performance. If users were to switch from their current implementations to CL, they would not want a performance regression. 1980's computers were slow so 'reasonable performance' translates to good performance by today's standards.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping any of the languages you named to be fast. Ruby is very similar to Smalltalk, and Oracle's primary JVM is essentially a slightly modified Smalltalk VM, so all the Ruby community has to do is to spend as much money, research, brainpower, PhDs, resources, and man-centuries making Ruby fast as the Java community did making Java fast, and Ruby could be at least as fast as Java.

In fact, both Rubinius and TruffleRuby have already demonstrated performance comparable to C in certain benchmarks, and I have high hopes especially for TruffleRuby to get even faster.